# Can recursive method calls share a variable of dictionary type in Python 3

Tags: python

I got the following error message `No value for argument 'd' in method call (no-value-for-parameter)`when I tried to solve LeetCode 364. Nested List Weight Sum II ([link](https://leetcode.com/problems/nested-list-weight-sum-ii/)) with the following code.

```
class Solution:
"""
@param nestedList: a list of NestedInteger
@return: the sum
"""
def depthSumInverse(self, nestedList):
    # Write your code here.
    d = collections.defaultdict(int)
    self.dfs(nestedList, 1, d)
    n = len(d)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        sum += d[i] * (n - i + 1)
    return sum

def dfs(self, nestedList, depth, d):
    ans = 0
    for e in nestedList:
        if e.isInteger():
            ans += e.getInteger()
        else:
            self.dfs(e.getList(), depth + 1)
    d[depth] += ans
```

I attempted to put keyword `nonlocal` to let the `dfs` method have the assess to the outer variable `d`. However, this modification doesn't work either:

```
class Solution:
"""
@param nestedList: a list of NestedInteger
@return: the sum
"""
def depthSumInverse(self, nestedList):
    # Write your code here.
    d = collections.defaultdict(int)
    self.dfs(nestedList, 1, d)
    n = len(d)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        sum += d[i] * (n - i + 1)
    return sum

def dfs(self, nestedList, depth, d):
    nonlocal d
    ans = 0
    for e in nestedList:
        if e.isInteger():
            ans += e.getInteger()
        else:
            self.dfs(e.getList(), depth + 1)
    d[depth] += ans
```

Finally, I resolved the problem with a self dictionary variable:

```
class Solution:
"""
@param nestedList: a list of NestedInteger
@return: the sum
"""
def depthSumInverse(self, nestedList):
    # Write your code here.
    self.d = collections.defaultdict(int)
    self.dfs(nestedList, 1)
    n = len(self.d)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        sum += self.d[i] * (n - i + 1)
    return sum

def dfs(self, nestedList, depth):
    ans = 0
    for e in nestedList:
        if e.isInteger():
            ans += e.getInteger()
        else:
            self.dfs(e.getList(), depth + 1)
    self.d[depth] += ans
```

I am wondering about the reason why the first two methods do not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be very wrong , but it looks like your error is just a typo.
In your first code example, you do this:

```
self.dfs(e.getList(), depth + 1)
```

However. your function `dfs()` takes 3 arguments(I don't count `self` here). You should call it like this:

```
self.dfs(e.getList(), depth + 1,d)
```

You second code example doesn't work for the same reason.